# Delete ElasticSearch indexes which matches a specific pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

How can one use `ElasticSearch curator` to delete old index which matches a specific pattern. Using `curator` like this will delete all indexes rather than the ones matching a pattern:

```
curator --host <ip address> delete indices --time-unit days --older-than 45 --timestring '%Y%m%d'
```

Assuming one wants to delete indexes from 45 days ago which matches `sample_index_*`, how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

curator --host  delete indices --time-unit days --older-than 45 --timestring '%Y%m%d' --prefix sample_

In addition to the prefix option, you can also use suffix and regex

Comment: The current (as of this posting, v3.5.0) version of Curator shows the arguments that can be applied to the command-line, including the above-mentioned `--prefix`.  The documentation for the `indices` sub-command can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/indices-subcommand.html)